# How do I show the color of a label on a image in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy. I inserted a label on an image. But it doesn't show the color of the label. It only shows the text as shown in the image. If you can please tell me how to show the color of the label.
[image]

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""

<Money_Manager>:
    Image:
        source:'image4.png'

    SmoothLabel:
        text: "Hello[![enter image description here][1]][1] World"
        size: 0.1,.1
        rgb: (255,255,255)

<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,255,255, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: .1,.1
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius

""")

class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):

    def build(self):

        return self

Money_Manager().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Did you mean you want to color the Hello World label from white to something else.

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<Money_Manager>:
    Image:
        source:'image4.png'

    SmoothLabel:
        text: "Hello World"
        size: 0.1,.1
        color: [255,100,0,1]

<SmoothLabel@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    border_radius: [18]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (255,0,0, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: .1,.1
            pos: self.pos
            radius: self.border_radius
""")

class Money_Manager(App, FloatLayout):

  def build(self):
      return self

Money_Manager().run()
```

With little change in your code line

```
rgb: (255,255,255)
```

to

```
color: [255,100,0,1]
```

I am able to colour it green. Is this what you want.